# echo a message on a new page

Tags: php, html

I want to echo a message on a new page after redirecting. but I only want the message to show once after reloading (redirecting) and on the next reload I want the message gone. is this at all possible? I give you an example:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "entry deleted"
   header("location: anotherpage.html")
```

on "anotherpage.php"

```
echo "$_SESSION['message']" // upon next reload $_SESSION['message'] = "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $_SESSION['message'];
unset($_SESSION['message']);
```

But I prefer to add a function to display messages, something like:

```
function setMessage($msg_body, $css_style = 'normalMsg') {

    $_SESSION['messages'][$css_style][] = $msg_body;

}


function showMessages() {

    if (empty($_SESSION['messages'])) return;

    foreach ($_SESSION['messages'] as $css_style=>$messages) {
        echo '<div class="'.$css_style.'">';
        echo implode($messages,'<br>');
        echo '</div>';
    }
    unset($_SESSION['messages']);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check, if message is set and valid

```
if (isset($_SESSION['message']) && $_SESSION['message']) {
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
    $_SESSION['message'] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be working as you suggested. (If I got you right).

Simply:

*the redirecting page* :

```
$_SESSION['message'] = 'test';
header('Location: anotherpage.php');
```

*on "anotherpage.php"* :

```
echo $_SESSION['message'];
$_SESSION['message'] = ''; // message will being empty on further reloads
```

Comment: It depends what function You will using to check if session variable are not exists. $_SESSION['message'] = ''; isset($_SESSION['message']) gives You true, empty() gives You true, is_null() //false etc. Best way to unset session variable is using unset() function.

Comment: it is nothing said about such a check.